# How do I stop html form from submitting blank fields in emailjs?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I have created a form like this and used onclick which triggers the `index.js` to submit the form even if the form is empty.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="sendMail()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My JavaScript file looks like this

```
function sendMail(){
    var params = {
        date: document.getElementById("date").value
    };

    const serviceID = "my_id";
    const templateID = "my_id";

    emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params).then((res) => {
        document.getElementById("date").value = ""; 
        console.log(res);
        alert("Done! Our Team will get back to you soon");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    
}
```

I have tried using another function to check form if it's empty as follows, but it doesn't work

```
function check() {
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  if (!date) {
    alert("Please fill in all fields");
    return;
  }else {
    sendMail();
  }
```

Comment: What you look for is called validation and there are a lot of ways doing it. The simplest one is to check for empty fields and prevent the `emailjs.send(...)` command from running untill every field is filled.

Answer (score 1):

The value isn't null just because it's empty.

```
if (date.length === 0) then
```

Comment: I tried doing it this way. But the problem still persist. I am not able to run the else part that is sendMail() if I have another method that is check()

Answer (score 1):

The button is inside a  element, and button type is submit. So when you click button it will trigger a form submit. When the inputs are empty, the email input has a required attribute which makes it invalid, so the form will not be submitted.
Try the code below:

```
function check(e) {
 // the 2 lines below will stop the default form submit action
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  if (!date) {
    alert("Please fill in all fields");
    return;
  }else {
    sendMail();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. It only works if the field is empty but the else part will not run.

Comment: @InnocentDengkhwMochahari    Well, you have a form element and the button type is submit. Which means when you click the button it will submit the form. So first you need to stop submitting the form.  function check(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();  // then logic  }